# Examples and/or tutorials on UISplitViewController and CRUD actions

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, crud

Are there any good examples on how to use UISplitViewController for CRUD actions?  I have come up empty in such a search, I keep finding iPhone examples, but they are of little help when working with iPad only applications.

Comment: Did you end up getting it working?

Comment: No, what I am really looking for is a best practice for using UISplitViewControllers to add, edit and delete data.  The iPhone examples make sense, but on iPad the HIG laysout using the UISplitViewController.  How do you tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have CRUD actions but just in case you wanna do it (uisplitviewcontroller) programmatically.. here's a good start..

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-landscape.html

and

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-portrait.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial with UISplitViewController (master/detail):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial